# extract all files from a directory that start with a specific word

Tags: c++, boost

I have a folder that havs files with these kind of names "In_YMD_xxx" and "Out_YMD_xxx" where YMD is year, month and day (exp. 20150101) and xxx is its idx such as 050. I am looking for a simple way to read the **name** of latest files (In_.. and Out_..) that were created using boost library in C++.

Here is an example of files that I have on my directory: "C:\Customer\AppleFruit\"

```
In_20141101_001
In_20150102_002
In_20150130_0101
In_20150201_001
Out_20140501_101
Out_20141101_101
Out_20150101_152
Out_20150201_191
```

Below is the code that i am trying to write in C++:

```
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"

boost::filesystem::path p( "C:\Customer\AppleFruit\");
typedef vector<path> vec; //sort path
vec inVec, outVec;
std::string inFilename, outFileName;

sort(v.begin(), v.end());
for (vec::const_iterator it (v.begin()); it != v.end(); ++it)
{
   if ( file_name_Starts_with_IN ) // here I am looking for the correct "if condition"
   inVec.push_back( *it);
   else if ( file_name_Starts_with_OUT ) //same thing here
   outVec.push_back( *it);
}
inFilename = inVec(end);
outFileName= outVec(end);
```

Any idea please..Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should escape the string literal containing your path or use / instead of \ as the path separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** after the comment.

If you want a more than two way partition, I'd suggest making it table-driven:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6f13db2c9b9a0dc)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {
    using boost::filesystem::path;
    using boost::filesystem::directory_iterator;
    using boost::make_iterator_range;

    path p("."); // or "C:\\Customer\\AppleFruit\\"

    std::map<std::string, std::vector<path> > bins {
        { "In_",  {} },
        { "Out_", {} },
      //{ "",     {} }, // remaining files
    };

    for(auto&& de: make_iterator_range(directory_iterator("."), {}))
        for(auto& bin: bins)
            if (de.path().filename().native().find(bin.first) == 0)
                bin.second.push_back(std::move(de));

    for(auto& bin: bins)
        for(auto& f : boost::sort(bin.second))
            std::cout << "Prefix '" << bin.first << "': " << f << "\n";
}
```

---

_Old answer: _

You can use `partition_copy` with a suitable predicate (here, I used a lambda):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a92eead65ba2adbd)</kbd>**

```
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::filesystem::path p("."); // or "C:\\Customer\\AppleFruit\\"

    std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> inVec, outVec;

    std::partition_copy(
            boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(p), {},
            back_inserter(inVec),
            back_inserter(outVec),
            [](boost::filesystem::directory_entry const& de) { 
                return de.path().filename().native().find("In_") == 0;
            ; });

    std::sort(inVec.begin(),  inVec.end());
    std::sort(outVec.begin(), outVec.end());

    for(auto& f : inVec)
    {
        std::cout << f << "\n";
    }
}
```

Lists all file names that start with `"In_"` (case sensitively). On Coliru, from  files created with

```
touch {In,Out}_{a..m}_file.txt
```

this means that only

```
"./In_a_file.txt"
"./In_b_file.txt"
"./In_c_file.txt"
"./In_d_file.txt"
"./In_e_file.txt"
"./In_f_file.txt"
"./In_g_file.txt"
"./In_h_file.txt"
"./In_i_file.txt"
"./In_j_file.txt"
"./In_k_file.txt"
"./In_l_file.txt"
"./In_m_file.txt"
```

are matched and printed, in sorted order

Comment: It is a good idea to use std::partition_copy but if there is any file with different name that was saved in the same directory by "mistakes", it will be extracted also on the Out_files...

Comment: @Sally Indeed. I didn't catch that requirement. In that case: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6f13db2c9b9a0dc)**